# ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2. ( Keras, Sklearn)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, scikit-learn, deep-learning

I'm trying to train a model using this code from the tutorial of Adrian Rosebrock using my custom dataset to detect the emotion facial expression.

```
INIT_LR = 1e-3
EPOCHS = 30
BS = 10

print("[INFO] loading images...")
imagePaths = list(paths.list_images(args["dataset"]))
data = []
labels = []


for imagePath in imagePaths:
# extract the class label from the filename
    label = imagePath.split(os.path.sep)[-2]


    image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    image = cv2.resize(image, (48, 48))

    data.append(image)
    labels.append(label)
data = np.array(data) / 255.0
labels = np.array(labels)

# perform one-hot encoding on the labels
lb = LabelBinarizer()
labels = lb.fit_transform(labels)
labels = to_categorical(labels)

(trainX, testX, trainY, testY) = train_test_split(data, labels,
test_size=0.20, stratify=labels, random_state=42) # line 80

trainAug = ImageDataGenerator(
   rotation_range=15,
   fill_mode="nearest")
baseModel = VGG16(weights="imagenet", include_top=False,
input_tensor=Input(shape=(48, 48, 3)))

headModel = baseModel.output
headModel = AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(4, 4))(headModel)
headModel = Flatten(name="flatten")(headModel)
headModel = Dense(64, activation="relu")(headModel)
headModel = Dropout(0.5)(headModel)
headModel = Dense(7, activation="softmax")(headModel)


model = Model(inputs=baseModel.input, outputs=headModel)

for layer in baseModel.layers:
layer.trainable = False

print("[INFO] compiling model...")
opt = Adam(lr=INIT_LR, decay=INIT_LR / EPOCHS)
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=opt,
metrics=["accuracy"])
print("[INFO] training head...")
H = model.fit_generator(

trainAug.flow(trainX, trainY, batch_size=BS),
steps_per_epoch=len(trainX) // BS,
validation_data=(testX, testY),
validation_steps=len(testX) // BS,
epochs=EPOCHS) # InvalidArgumentError : Incompatible shapes
```

This code worked for two classes ( binary classification ).
I would like to make this script train a dataset with 7 classes.
I made some changes but when I execute this code, I got this error:

> [INFO] loading images...
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "train_mask.py", line 80, in
>
> test_size=0.20, stratify=labels, random_state=42), in check_array
>
> % (array.ndim, estimator_name))
>
> ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2.

What should I do to make this code working for Multilabel classification, not a binary classification?

Comment: What's the shape of `data`?

Comment: The dimension is (48,48)

Comment: Not the dimension, the `image.shape`, I am guessing it is `(48, 48, 3)` cause it is a `RGB` image right?

Comment: Yes , is it ,  I mean `(48, 48, 3)`

Comment: What is the shape of `labels` after executing `to_categorical(labels)`? Also, Please, fix indentation on the loop for images paths

Comment: The shape of `labels` is `(981, 7, 2)` 981 => number of images, 7 => the numbers of folders in dataset folder , but for 2 I don't have any idea what can be!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually stratify parameter takes an array of strata or labels and not one-hot-encoded labels.

If you remove stratify does it run? If so just remove create a variable like hotlabels so you don't overwrite your original labels array.

This does depend on the train_test_split function you are using. If it's scikit it should be an array of labels.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html

Comment: Thanks, This solution is worked for me now, but I got other errors for now  tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [10,7] vs. [10]
         [[{{node metrics/acc/Equal}}]]
         [[{{node ConstantFoldingCtrl/loss/dense_1_loss/broadcast_weights/assert_broadcastable/AssertGuard/Switch_0}}]]

Comment: No , The shape of labels is `(981, 7, 2)`

Comment: Is this in the compile or fitting stage?  Wouldn't this be after the code you have posted above?

Comment: Yes, I have updated my code and I have added a comment in the line that cause the error.

Comment: @abdou_dev, Did you removed `stratify` in order to get it working? If so, keep in mind that not stratified data on greatly imbalanced dataset could lead to bias towards the majority class.

Comment: Yes I removed `stratify` from `train_test_split` , so what can I do in this case?

Comment: You should be able to put in the stratify again with `stratifylabels = np.array(labels)` before the hot-encoding. Then use that as the stratify argument.

Although if your emojii face expressions are already pretty representative it shouldn't be that important.

Comment: is it that you want to say : `stratifylabels=np.array(labels)
# perform one-hot encoding on the labels
lb = LabelBinarizer()
labels = lb.fit_transform(labels)
labels = to_categorical(labels)
print(labels.shape)

# partition the data into training and testing splits using 80% of
# the data for training and the remaining 20% for testing

(trainX, testX, trainY, testY) = train_test_split(data, labels,
 test_size=0.20,stratify=stratifylabels, random_state=42,)`

Comment: Sorry but your solution doesn't work for me , I will try to ask a new question on Stackoverflow