# InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [10,7] vs. [10] [[{{node metrics/acc/Equal}}]]

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm newer to deep learning and Keras library, I'm trying to use the tutorial of Adrian Rosebrock ( Detect COVID-19 in X-ray images ) use binary classification.
My object is training for more than two classes. I have made some changes to apply the category classification. ( 7 classes to detect the face emotion).
I have posted recently an error that I got with training:
  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60921502/valueerror-found-array-with-dim-3-estimator-expected-2-keras-sklearn/60921915?noredirect=1#comment107783178_60921915)

and I have solved it but I have another error:

the output of labels shape and data shape:

`(981, 7, 2) # labels shape
(981, 224, 224, 3) # data shape`

I'm trying to train the dataset using this script ( after applying some modifications ).

```
INIT_LR = 1e-3
EPOCHS = 100
BS = 10

print("[INFO] loading images...")
imagePaths = list(paths.list_images(args["dataset"]))
data = []
labels = []

for imagePath in imagePaths:
    label = imagePath.split(os.path.sep)[-2]
    image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    image = cv2.resize(image, (224, 224))
    data.append(image)
    labels.append(label)

data = np.array(data) / 255.0
labels = np.array(labels)

stratifylabels=np.array(labels)
lb = LabelBinarizer()
labels = lb.fit_transform(labels)
labels = to_categorical(labels) # line 77
print(labels.shape)
print(data.shape)

(trainX, testX, trainY, testY) = train_test_split(data, labels,
    test_size=0.20, random_state=42,)

trainAug = ImageDataGenerator(
rotation_range=15,
fill_mode="nearest")

baseModel = VGG16(weights="imagenet", include_top=False,
    input_tensor=Input(shape=(224, 224, 3)))

headModel = baseModel.output
headModel = AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(4, 4))(headModel)
headModel = Flatten(name="flatten")(headModel)
headModel = Dense(64, activation="relu")(headModel)
headModel = Dropout(0.5)(headModel)
headModel = Dense(7, activation="softmax")(headModel)

model = Model(inputs=baseModel.input, outputs=headModel)
for layer in baseModel.layers:
layer.trainable = False
print("[INFO] compiling model...")
opt = Adam(lr=INIT_LR, decay=INIT_LR / EPOCHS)
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=opt,
metrics=["accuracy"])
```

I have got this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>      File "train_mask.py", line 130, in 
>      epochs=EPOCHS)
>      tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [10,7] vs. [10]
>           [[{{node metrics/acc/Equal}}]]
>           [[{{node >ConstantFoldingCtrl/loss/dense_1_loss/broadcast_weights/assert_broadcastable/AssertGuard/Switch_0}}]]

Note: That when I comment the line 77 , the training work fine but the results are very bad with accuracy=`1.2xx`

Answer (score 0):

You could either keep line 77 and change your compile function from:

```
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=opt,metrics=["categorical_accuracy"])
```

or you could remove line 77 and change your compile function to:

```
model.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=opt,metrics=["sparse_categorical_accuracy"])
```

Comment: I got another error `tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Can not squeeze dim[2], expected a dimension of 1, got 2
         [[{{node metrics/acc/Squeeze}}]]
         [[{{node loss/dense_1_loss/broadcast_weights/assert_broadcastable/is_valid_shape/has_valid_nonscalar_shape/has_invalid_dims/ExpandDims_1}}]]`

Comment: That is because you are claiming and also creating a model for multiclass classification with 7 classes. If this is true, then your labels should have a shape of (981, 7) and not (981, 7, 2). You should fix your labels

Comment: The fix of labels can be only by making a comment in the line 77. That's the problem

Comment: You should either make your dataset fit the model or create a model that fits to your datasets. For your current model, your labels should have a shape of (981, 7). Best of luck.

Comment: I have used another tutorial from the same person "Adrian Rosebrock", it works but also the results are not good for many images from the dataset, I think that the problem is in the dataset itself, However, to make a prediction you should have a large dataset, every class should have many images to make good training.